# Uploading file to YouTube fails with ShareIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube

I have spent several hours now trying to upload videos to YouTube using a ShareIntent, and have read and tried everything that I could find. When I try to upload an mp4 to YouTube from my app, the progress freezes at 19%, and it is showing that the file size is 5.7MB, but it is actually 1.1MB. If I choose to upload to Facebook, gmail, or anything else, it will upload with no problems.If I try to upload the same video from the Gallery to YouTube, it will work fine.

Here is my getShareIntent method:

```
private Intent getShareIntent() {
    Intent intent =  new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    ContentValues content = new ContentValues(4);
    content.put(Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    content.put(Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
    content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, "myVideo");
    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();             
    Uri data = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, content);
    intent.setType("video/mp4");
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, data);

    return intent;
}
```

My ShareActionIntent is initialized here when my ActionBar menu is created:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.saved_menu, menu);

     deleteItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_delete);
     shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);

     shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);
     shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getShareIntent());

     return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }
```

This is being called from the onPageSelected of my viewPager:

```
shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getShareIntent());
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am not getting any errors in my logcat or from anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to my getShareIntent() method. So far, it seems to work ok and uploads to YouTube just fine now.

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent scanFileIntent = new Intent(
Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri);
sendBroadcast(scanFileIntent);
```